# Create a single route for every controller and method in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Can I set a default route, so when I have a request like `/home/index` and `/home`, it would redirect to the `home` controller's `index` action, just like in other frameworks?
I know that I can set them one by one but I don't want to add a route for every request, I would like to use only one route for all requests.

Answer (score 4):

Theres two other types of controllers beside the basic controller. You can create these by specifying a special route to your controller. With this technique you don't have to create a route for every method just one per controller.

### [Resource Controller](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers)

This will create all the methods with the corresponding HTTP verb you need for managing one resource like a user or a product. There is a [table in the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers) that contains which predefined route matches the predefined methods of the controller, that represents an action you can do with a method, like edit, create, destroy, etc:

[image: Resource controller route-method list]

Anyway, you still free to add extra methods and routes beside the resource controller methods and routes, just keep in mind that you have to do this before defining the resource controller route:

```
//Extra route for the resource controller.
Route::get('home/profile', 'HomeController@profile');
//Resource controller routes.
Route::resource('home', 'HomeController');
```

### [RESTful Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers)

I think this is what will fit better for your needs.
Creating a RESTful controller will automatically create a route for all methods that begins with a HTTP verb.

```
Route::controller('home', 'HomeController');
```

After this, you can create methods like these in your `HomeController`:

```
public function getIndex() {
    //Code.
}
public function postProfile() {
    //Code.
}
```

The framework will automatically create the routes for them, so you can access `postProfile()` through a HTTP POST to the `/home/profile` route. Also you can access `getIndex()` through a HTTP GET to the `/home/index`.

The [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers) also mentions:

> The **index** methods will respond to the root URI handled by the controller.

In our case that means that you can acces your `getIndex()` method through the `/home/index` and the `/home` routes too.
If you have a method that has multiple words in it (a word start with a camel case letter), then the generated route will have a `-` between the words, so the method `getAdminProfile()` will have a route called `home/admin-profile`.

Also as I told at the resource controller section, you can still create regular routes, just be sure to create them before you create the RESTful controller's route.

### Final answer

Create a route: `Route::controller('home', 'HomeController');` call your root method `getIndex()` and prefix every other method with a HTTP verb e.g. `userTool()` should become `getUserTools()`.

Comment: I know this can work,but I don't want to every url add a route.Can I set just one route for all requestes?

Comment: @jifei Updated my answer with a detailed description for you.

Comment: Is there also solution for Laravel 6.x? I read that i have to use Route::resource but I can't seem to get it to work with dynamic routes, except the fixed ones.

Comment: Solution no longer working for Laravel 9. Is there another method for doing so besides using `Route::apiResource('site', SiteController::class);` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `Route::controller()` just name your `index()` method `getIndex()`.